# Android Studio:Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:

Tags: java, android

Android Studio导入项目项目出现
Gradle sync failed: Cause: startup failed:
script 'E:\APP\XHTTP2\okdownload\gradle\gradle-mvn-push.gradle': 51: unable to resolve class MavenDeployment
@ line 51, column 26.
beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }
^

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.